# Nested FAB moving in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

I'm trying to create an activity with an CoordinatorLayout, Viewpager and in there a normal view with a FAB. The layout I'm trying to create is:

```
- CoordinatorLayout
    - ViewPager
        - View with FAB
        - View
        - etc
```

So in my case I need to include the FAB in the view inside the ViewPager.
My problem is right now (in a simplified application):
https://gfycat.com/VacantAdmiredBedlingtonterrier
The problem in the GIF is that the FAB moves out of the screen. It moves exactly the height of the toolbar.

What I want is that the FAB would stay put at its position but inside the viewpager and in the view.

The XML of this view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

As shown in the XML is that the FAB is not in the scrollview but is inside the FrameLayout, which would represent a ViewPager.

Is there any way to make this FAB stay put at it's position but keeping the view inside a viewpager?